# Optimal algorithm for happy numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

Given number is n digits find 2n digits numbers 
that, for example

given number is 3 then 6n numbers are from 100000 -999999

then find count of those numbers that for example

```
       123213
1 + 2 + 3 = 2 + 1 + 3
        6 = 6
```

I found and wrote a program for calculating little numbers, but I need the fastest algorithm to find those numbers. Ideas?

my program :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter  n ");

int say = scan.nextInt();

say *= 2;

int low = (int) Math.pow(10, say - 1);
int max = (int) Math.pow(10, say) - 1;

int counter = 0;

int first = 0;
int last = 0;

for (int i = low; i <= max; i++) {

    int number = i;
    first = 0;
    last = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < say / 2; j++) {

        int k = number % 10;
        first += k;
        number /= 10;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < say / 2; j++) {

        int k = number % 10;
        last += k;
        number /= 10;
    }

    if (first == last) {
        //  System.out.println(i);
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Um, I'm not sure that you're describing [happy numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)

Comment: nevermind, it actually would work, my mistake. But yes, it is brute force, but I know a qualification for CR is that the code must be functional, just not optimal.

Comment: so much cpu just to find funny numbers :-)

Comment: @Leo: I believe the ultimate goal is to train one's brain, much less to find the numbers

Comment: Yes this code works but i need optimal algorithm. I know this is not happy numbers but teacher said that this is happy numbers ) soviet teachers are best !

Comment: Now, I really don't understand why this is supposed to be off-topic. We have countless examples of people asking for algorithms without code, those don't get closed. So are we actually punishing OP for trying a suboptimal implementation instead of asking just for the algorithm? What kind of message does that send? People, don't be so stupid as to include your own suboptimal code because then the question will get closed?

Comment: The thing is, nothing about this code can probably be kept if one wants a better algorithm. I don't see how that's Code Review.

Comment: @JasonC: I don't get it. I don't see the condition that the digits must add up to 2n. I also don't see the condition that repeated digits are not allowed in one half

Comment: @NiklasB. I agree with you, changing the algorithm would basically be rewriting the whole thing. I didn't consider what optimizations could be taken at first, and thought that perhaps it would be better on CR.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't have enough rep for that, otherwise I would

Comment: @JasonC: Oh okay, I thought combinations would be without repetitions. Please also consider reopening the question, please see my comments above. I think there is an `O(n polylog n)` algorithm

Comment: @NiklasB. We do [interesting work](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1440/9357) in Code Review! Please check us out!

Comment: @200_success: I'm sure you do, but I don't see "let me throw away your code because it's exponential when it can be linear" on that list.

Comment: @NiklasB. I am rewriting my comment though, because the "mirror" requirement definitely was to be a mistake on my part.

Comment: Step 1: Iterate over all numbers from 100-999 (e.g. `10^(n-1)` to `(10^n)-1`). This is your first 3 digits. Compute the sum. Step 2: For each of those, determine all *permutations*, with repetition (not combinations, order is significant) of numbers 0-9 that add up to that sum. Step 3: For each of those permutations, the n digits from step 1 followed by the n digits from step 2 are valid numbers.

Comment: @NiklasB. Oh, and I will not vote to re-open, as in any case "too-broad" covers the question.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, we sometimes recommend [starting from scratch](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1353/9357)!

Comment: @JasonC: Okay, in that case I would ask you how OP could have decomposed the problem into more managable pieces if he doesn't have an initial approach? [We currently fight over this very argument and the status of Stack Overflow with regard to programming contest problems](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/the-setting-is-competition-but-the-activity-is-still-programming/13701) because of a closed Stack Exchange proposal. This question is a superb example of my standpoint that questions about competitive programming have a very hard time here

Comment: Jacon C , i don't understand  what you want to say ,please  explain clearly

Comment: @user3416739: Now that the question is reopened, can you please clarify what constitues a happy number? Your definition is not very clear. For example, do the digits have to sum up to 2n or is this just a conincidence in your example? And can digits be repeated? How large can *n* get etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers are called lucky tickets in Russian ([a link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82) to ru.wikipedia.org). Yet, I don't seem to find a good explanation in English besides [these slides](http://math.mit.edu/~rothvoss/18.304.1PM/Presentations/1-Noor-LuckyTickets.pdf).

Basically, let us say we have `2n` digits, and we want the sum of first `n` be equal to the sum of last `n`. We first count `c(d,s)`: the number of sequences of `d` digits which have sum `s`. Here, `0 <= d <= n` and `0 <= s <= 9n`. This can be done by dynamic programming: `c(0,0)=1`, and for `d > 0`, `c(d,s) = c(d-1,s-0) + c(d-1,s-1) + c(d-1,s-2) + ... + c(d-1,s-9)` since we can take any sequence of `d-1` digits and write another digit from `0` to `9`.

Now, the total number of lucky tickets is the sum for different `s` of the numbers of lucky tickets where the sum of the first `n` digits is `s` and the sum of the last `n` digits is `s`. When `s` is fixed, this number is equal to `c(n,s) * c(n,s)`: there are exactly `c(n,s)` ways to choose the first half, and equally many to choose the second one.

Thus the answer is `sum[s=0..9n] c(n,s)^2`.

There are other solutions as well involving advanced maths, but for a programmer's assignment, this would suffice. Once again, I can't find a proper source in English — sorry! [Here](http://ega-math.narod.ru/Quant/Tickets.htm) are a few popular articles in Russian, for what it's worth.

**Edit**: If you in fact need to account for numbers 100000 to 999999, not 000000 to 999999, a patch would be to calculate `sum[s=0..9n] (c'(n,s) * c(n,s))`, where `c'(n,s)` is the same table but calculated with disabled addition of zero digit when adding the first digit.

Comment: +1 (Although I think it may need a small,easy adjustment to avoid counting 012012 as an answer for n=3 - the question only wants answers between 100,000 and 999,999)

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz: Added a patch. Thank you, that slipped away from me.